# How to ignore characters on a MYSQL SELECT LIKE %...%

Tags: mysql, select, wildcard, sql-like

I have a table with a `phone` column, where data may have spaces, dots,dashes or + signs between the numbers.
I need to do a search with LIKE wildcards that ignore all those characters, for example:

- a record may have phone as "+123-456 78.90"
- a query looking for "6789" or any complete or incomplete sequence of proper digits in order should bring up that record.

Unfortunately I cant cleanup the original table to remove the non-digit characters and do a plain SELECT LIKE %...%.

MYSQL has functions to substitute/remove characters from strings, but can't find a way to use them inside a query with a widlcarded LIKE.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Which is the server side language ? PHP ?

Comment: It says mysql and Henry's talking about queries ;)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I see two ways doing this:

1. If you allow only a few extra characters than you can prepare a string which is stripped from these extra characters and you use the LIKE operator you normally would

   ```
   select * from phoneTable where replace(replace(phone, '+', ''), '-', '') LIKE '%123%'
   ```

   Of course you need as many replace calls as the number of allowed extra characters
2. You use regular expressions, let's say you are searching for pattern 123

   ```
   select * from phoneTable where phone REGEXP '.*1[^0-9]*2[^0-9]*3'
   ```

Comment: Once adding the '%..%' to the first option, both of them do the job properly. Much thanks for your help.

Comment: You are right, I forgot out the wildcards, and I didn't try to run the queries. Answer corrected.

Comment: i'd guess first option is faster

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem with partnumbers and unwanted characters.
My solution was

```
SELECT * FROM parts WHERE replace(partnumber, '-', '') LIKE '$searchterm%';
```

Comment: how is this answer different from the accepted one?