# Ignore symbols in laravel query

Tags: laravel

If i have product's title "Svarstyklės, iki 32 kg Toko" and i am trying to search for "Svarstyklės iki 32 kg Toko" (without comma) query does not return anything. Is there any way to ignor comma?

This is my code now:

`$query->where('title', 'LIKE', "%{$search}%");`

Comment: There is no easy way to do this. If you want to be most flexible you could create an indexed system for all words in your titles and then search the indexes for all words of your search string.

Comment: I think you should consider using a proper search like elasticsearch or (if you are using MySQL) using a [FULLTEXT index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html) if you find yourself needing to do this sort of more advanced search more often

Answer (score 0):

you can use this after your query

```
$yourString = str_replace(",","", $yourString);
```

Comment: but i need to ignore symbols that are in db columns, how can i replace them?

Comment: check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9850180/how-to-ignore-characters-on-a-mysql-select-like